# In Keras, why testing a model loaded with load_model is so much slower than load_weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have in Keras a RNN with 5 layers of LSTM cells. This model is already trained, and now I am testing it.

On one hand, I use the function "load_model" from tensorflow.keras.models. Something like

```
model = load_model("mymodel.hdf5")
```

On the other hand, I first create an empty model of my RNN, and then I load the weights, something like

```
loadmodeltemp = load_model("mymodel.hdf5")
model = functionThatWillCreateMyRNN()
model.set_weights(loadmodeltemp.get_weights())
```

The second option is on general 2xfaster than the first option. I mean when the model is already loaded and you are training or testing it. I am not speaking about the load_model itself, but about what happens afterwards.

I am using archlinux, tensorflow 2.0.0, and keras is imported like "from tensorflow import keras", and the version is 2.2.4-tf.

The GPU is a 1080TI. When forcing CPU it is around 4x slower than the second option.

What's load_model doing that it is causing everything to go slower? It's just that it'd be neater to have a load_model function that does everything, instead of having to load the model and then load the weights.